# Spring does not enter custom validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, acl, spring-validator

I have added 4 custom validators to make some checks in my controller. 3 of them working but the `ValidObjectIdentity` one does not work.

Here is my constraint-mapping.xml

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.1.xsd"
                     xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping" version="1.1">

    <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AccessControlEntryImpl" ignore-annotations="true">
        <field name="sid">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
            <constraint annotation="package.validation.SidExists"/>
            <constraint annotation="package.validation.NonMatchingSid"/>
        </field>
        <field name="acl">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
        </field>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclImpl">
        <field name="objectIdentity">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
            <constraint annotation="package.validation.ValidObjectIdentity"/>
        </field>
    </bean>

    <bean class="package.AccessControlEntryController">
        <method name="create">
            <parameter type="org.springframework.security.acls.model.AccessControlEntry">
                <constraint annotation="package.validation.ValidEntry"/>
            </parameter>
        </method>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/acl")
@Validated
public class AccessControlEntryController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/entry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public AccessControlEntry create(@Valid @RequestBody AccessControlEntry entry){
        return aclService.createAccessControlEntry(entry);
    }
}
```

For reference I will put here the structure of `AccessControlEntryImpl` and `AclImpl`

```
public class AccessControlEntryImpl implements AccessControlEntry, AuditableAccessControlEntry {

    private final Acl acl;
    private Permission permission;
    private final Serializable id;
    private final Sid sid;
    private boolean auditFailure = false;
    private boolean auditSuccess = false;
    private final boolean granting;

}
```

```
public class AclImpl implements Acl, MutableAcl, AuditableAcl, OwnershipAcl {
    private Acl parentAcl;
    private transient AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy;
    private transient PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy;
    private final List<AccessControlEntry> aces = new ArrayList<>();
    private ObjectIdentity objectIdentity;
    private Serializable id;
    private Sid owner; // OwnershipAcl
    private List<Sid> loadedSids = null;
}
```

I can see that the working validators are directly related with the AccessControlEntry but the `ObjectIdentity` is related to class `Acl`. Even though `AccessControlEntry` have `Acl` class in itself it does not go validator. Is there a way to validate `ObjectIdentity` like others?

Here is a validator incase you want to see

```
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidObjectIdentityValidator.class)
public @interface ValidObjectIdentity {

    String message() default "{package.ValidObjectIdentity.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class ValidObjectIdentityValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidObjectIdentity, ObjectIdentity> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ObjectIdentity identity, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      // Logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you were hoping for `ValidObjectIdentity` to fire when validating `AccessControlEntryImpl`?

Cascaded validation doesn't happen by default. You need a `@Valid` annotation on `AccessControlEntryImpl.acl` or a `<valid/>` node for the corresponding XML mapping:

```
<field name="acl">
    <valid/>
</field>
```